# Tranposing a single column into rows and grouping microsoft server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table in the following format;

```
ID | Factors | Value  
---------------------
1  |    A    |  4542
1  |    B    |  454
1  |    C    |  43
```

I need to transpose the Factors column and group the id column so I get the following result;

```
ID|  A   |  B  | C  |
1   | 4542 | 454 | 43 |
```

I've looked into the pivot function but From what I've read its very memory intensive and I'm dealing with 1000's and ID's and values.

I've tried creating a table with the columns that I want but no idea how I could insert the correct data into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two common ways to achieve this are either Pivot:

```
SELECT ID AS NMI, [A], [B], [C]
FROM 
MyTable
PIVOT
(
    SUM(Value)
    FOR Factors in ([A], [B], [C])
) pvt;
```

Or using a manual CASE ... WHEN projection with a grouped aggregate:

```
SELECT 
    ID AS NMI, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN Factors = 'A' THEN Value END) AS [A], 
    SUM(CASE WHEN Factors = 'B' THEN Value END) AS [B],
    SUM(CASE WHEN Factors = 'C' THEN Value END) AS [C]
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY ID;
```

[Fiddle of both here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/38479/2)

Comment: This works besides the fact my values are all NULLS, could this be an issue with my data though?

Comment: NULLs are ignored in aggregates, unless all values in the grouped column are NULL, in which case `SUM()` will be also be NULL.